# Is it okay to use designated initializers in aggregate initialization for keyword arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, c++20, keyword-argument

## Introduction

Using names arguments on function call allows the developer to understand code more easily.
It seems like it's not widespread in C++. Is it?

## Examples

First, I want to show you examples of what I mean.

In Python, we can use keyword arguments like this

```
def f(x, y):
    return x + y

f(x=1, y=2)
```

In JS we have a destructuring

```
function f({x, y})
{
    return x + y;
}

f({x: 1, y: 2})
```

## Wishes

In C++20 there is a feature called designated initializers. These can be used to write names of parameters explicitly, though there is a problem: anonymous structures cannot be used as a parameter type like this

```
int f(struct { int x; int y; } args)
{
    return args.x + args.y;
}

f({.x = 1, .y = 2});
```

So, I should use

```
struct f
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int f(struct f args)
{
    return args.x + args.y;
}

f({.x = 1, .y = 2});
```

I can use a union to systemize arguments usage for functions in a file

```
union Arguments
{
    struct f
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    };
};

int f(struct Arguments::f args)
{
    return args.x + args.y;
}

f({.x = 1, .y = 2});
```

Is the code like this okay, or it's better to not use names and remember signatures of all functions?

Comment: Even `union`-s can have constructors. And you'll better use [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), maybe [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch How will the `std::variant` help me with named arguments?

Comment: It does not help with named arguments but is a good way to get [tagged unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) which might be your actual needs. Your question lacks motivation !

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't think it's applicable here. If I add a function `g`, I will add `struct g` to the union. If I'll use `std::variant` instead, it will allow providing these `variant` variables both to `f` and `g`. I use `union` here as a container like a `namespace`. Maybe it's better to use a `namespace` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With plain function arguments it is a compiler error if you don't provide an initializer for a function parameter. Whereas with *aggregate initialization* the missing members are value-initialized. So, these two methods of passing function arguments are not equivalent with regards to compile time checking whether all function arguments are explicitly provided.

Also, individual function arguments are more likely to be passed in registers, whereas only structures of small size can be passed in registers. In other words, packing function arguments into a structure can make calls less efficient.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about the compile-time check of the fact that all needed parameters are provided. This makes the use of the structure as an argument error-prone.

Comment: @Charlie: Another problems with using structs to pass parameters is argument forwarding. You can't do `make_shared<T>({.arg1 = ..., .arg2 = ...})` without explicitly specifying the struct name, since aggregate initialization requires that the compiler know the type being used. And `make_shared` doesn't have the type in its signature. This is true for any forwarding scenario.

Comment: Efficiency of arguments passing is an ABI issue (and can be surprising for x86-64 ABI on Linux)